# Vertically Aligning IMGs inside an li element

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I've tried everything from adding line-height, to changing the 'display' property to 'table-cell' to the li, but somehow i cant seem to get the images to be vertically aligned.

the css:

```
ul.columns { list-style: none; padding:25px }

ul.columns li {width:180px; height:180px; float:left; margin:16px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; border:1px solid gray}

ul.columns li img {margin:auto; display:block;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Sdt8M/3/

appreciate the help guys...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do those images need block display? If not, you can just give those `li`s a `line-height:180px`, and `vertical-align:middle` those images.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sdt8M/20/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html

Comment: thanks. it will certainly have the answer, hopefully. in fact i'd read about the inline-block property before, but heard it's not fully supported.

Answer (score 0):

hey try this..
Add `padding-top:10px` to `ul.columns li`

ul.columns { list-style: none; padding:25px }

```
ul.columns li {width:180px; height:180px; padding-top:10px; float:left; margin:16px; position:relative; overflow:hidden; border:1px solid gray}

ul.columns li img {margin:auto; display:block;}
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: that wont do cuz the image's height may vary and this would only add space at the top. thanks anywyas.

Comment: try with less padding to 'ul' and remove margin-top from 'li' and use padding-top to 'li'..just try this..